# Stitching grids of varying grid spacing

Tags: python, numpy

I read data from binary files into `numpy` arrays with `np.fromfile`. These data represent *Z* values on a grid for which spacing and shape are known so there is no problem reshaping the 1D array into the the shape of the grid and plotting with `plt.imshow`. So if I have *N* grids I can plot *N* subplots showing all data in one figure but what I'd really like to do is plot them as one image.

I can't just stack the arrays because the data in each array is spaced differently and because they have different shapes.

My idea was to "supersample" all grids to the spacing of the finest grid, stack and plot but I am not sure that is such a good idea as these grid files can become quite large.

By the way: Let's say I wanted to do that, how do I go from:

```
    0, 1, 2
    3, 4, 5
```

to:

```
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2
    3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5
    3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5
```

I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks,

Shahar

Comment: you can write smth like `loop` which will be append each element to the matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer if you just plot is: don't. `plt.imshow` has a keyword argument `extent` which you can use to zoom the imagine when plotting. Other then that I would suggest scipy.ndimage.zoom, with order=0, it is equivalent to repeating values, but you can zoom to any size easily or use a different order to get some smooth interpolation. `np.tile` could be an option for very simple zooming too.

Here is an example:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
b = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)

plt.imshow(a, extent=[0,1,0,1], interpolation='none')
plt.imshow(b, extent=(1,2,0,1), interpolation='none')
# note scaling is "broke"
plt.xlim(0,2)
```

of course to get the same color range for both, you should add `vim=...` and `vmax` keywords.

Comment: I use `im.show`. 'extent' isn't what I'm looking for, I need the entire extent of each grid/array/file/whatever you want to call it. I don't need to zoom I need to bring everything together so I can plot in one image.

Comment: @Shahar so you want to do actual _calculations_ on them and not just plot them. Then use `scipy.ndimage.zoom` probably, unless you do not have scipy. If this is all very regular and you need to be extra careful with RAM, there may be other options, but then plese tell us more about what you _actually_ do with them, as the critical step seems not just the plotting.

Comment: I do make some calculations but that is not the problem. As I described above, I can see via `plt.imshow` the results of all the manipulations I make but once each "patch" has been processed I want to join them together into one image. I realize some parts of my image will be over-sampled versions of lower resolution patches but I don't care about that.

Comment: @Shahar Then, please explain why the `extent` keyword is not what you want. Did you _try_ it?

Comment: I don't understand how I can pass multiple data arrays to imshow and have them display as one image. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't, you pass each alone with the correct extent... It should work, unless you get some artifacts due to that... I admit though, if you want interpolation between two of those arrays, thats not an option.

Comment: okay... I'll try that in a second but just to make sure I get it: Instead of starting a new subplot with a new axis instance I call `imshow` again with the next patch stating the extent it should go to?

Comment: I tried what you suggested but like I said, only one patch is drawn at the time, I want all patches drawn together as one image, not in subplots. I don't need any interpolation between patches. I guess I'll look into combining them into one large array before plotting with `imshow`. I'll have a look at `scipy.ndimage.zoom` but in the meantime I used `np.repeat` twice. once to repeat each element on the vector and once more to repeat each vector.

Comment: You are just fooled by the autoscaling. Might want to throw in `aspect='auto'`, I have added an example to the answer...

Comment: GOT IT! It was the `xlim` and `ylim` that were killing me. as they are set automatically, I was not seeing the previously ploted data only the current. Thanks for that, I would have pulled quite a bit of hair until I would have figured that out.